# jquery dialog opens multiple instances when within update panel and filter event is triggered

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Wow what a title...Sorry folks my jquery skills are lacking here.  I've got a jquery ui dialog box like so:

```
    $("#dialogAssignedTo").hide();
    $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: "form:first",
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true
    });
```

It opens on the click of a hyperlink:

```
 $("#MainContent_hlAT").click(function (evt) {
                $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog("open");
                evt.preventDefault();
            });
```

I've got a hidden field that stores the state of the dialog across server side post backs. Basically if the server side code has assigned the hidden field a 1 it maintains keeping the dialog open.  If its 0 it is hidden like so:

```
    if ($("#MainContent_hdnOpenAssignedTo").val() === "1") {
        $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog("open");
    } else {
        $("#dialogAssignedTo").hide();
    }
```

This all works fine...Now my problem.  I've got multiple drop downs (asp.net drop downs) that cascade.  Selecting one drop down filters the second, and so on.  This also works fine...however what I noticed is the page does a post back and then the dialog reopens..Its fine and works however I dont like the refreshing / flicker of the page.  So I decided to add the drop down's that are within the jquery ui dialog as Updatepanel triggers:

```
 <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dialogAssignedToddlBA"/>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dialogAssignedToddlBU"/>
 </Triggers>
```

So basically the whole page along with the jquery ui dialog is wrapped in an asp.net updatepanel.  The issue is the asyncpostback looks like it works but it opens up the dialog again and again after every SelectedIndexChanged event of the drop down.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'd like the drop downs to cascade in an async postback so that I do not see the flickering...

## Edit

Per the comments I am providing more information...

For instance, the dialog is simply a table of drop down values (disregard the fact that tables suck for the time being...), here is the sample html:

```
 <div id="dialogAssignedTo" title="Company Assigned To">
                <table style="height:500px; width:500px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDBA" runat="server" Text="BA:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField">
                            <asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" ID="dialogAssignedToddlBA" ToolTip="Select BA..." runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dialogAssignedToddlBA_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDBU" runat="server" Text="BU:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField"><asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" ID="dialogAssignedToddlBU" ToolTip="Select BU..." AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dialogAssignedToddlBU_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDATCountry" runat="server" Text="Country:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField"><asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Country..." ID="dialogAssignedToddlCountry" ToolTip="Select Country..." AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dialogAssignedToddlCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>

                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDATRegion" runat="server" Text="Region:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField"><asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select Region..." ID="dialogAssignedToddlRegion" ToolTip="Select Region..." AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dialogAssignedToddlRegion_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDATCity" runat="server" Text="City:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField"><asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" data-placeholder="Select City..." ID="dialogAssignedToddlCity" ToolTip="Select City..." AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dialogAssignedToddlCity_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDC" runat="server" Text="Company:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField"><asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" ID="dialogAssignedToddlCompanies" ToolTip="Select Company..." AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dialogAssignedToddlCompanies_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="labelField"><asp:Label ID="lblDU" runat="server" Text="User:"></asp:Label></td>
                        <td class="valueField"><asp:DropDownList class="chosen-select" ID="dialogAssignedToddlUsers" ToolTip="Select User..." runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
                        <td colspan="4" style="text-align:right;">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSaveAssignedTo" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSaveAssignedTo_Click" ToolTip="Submit / Save changes?" /></td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
         </div>
```

Notice the events for each drop down list (OnSelectedIndexChanged events).  That means these drop downs cascade..Here is where my problem lies.  The minute I select a drop down value the form goes out and comes back in (it basically refreshes).  This is fine however it causes a flicker to occur and bring back the dialog.  I would assume since the dialog is inside a page update panel (that is the whole page is in an update panel) that the flickering would not happen.  Any other drop down on the page is fine, its just drop downs within the dialog div.

An example code behind of one of the drop downs is as follows:

```
protected void dialogAssignedToddlBA_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            error.Visible = false;
            hdnOpenAssignedTo.Value = "1";
            var result = GetBUDataSet(dialogAssignedToddlBA.SelectedItem.Value);

            dialogAssignedToddlBU.DataSource = result;
            dialogAssignedToddlBU.DataTextField = "BusinessUnit1";
            dialogAssignedToddlBU.DataValueField = "BusinessUnitID";
            dialogAssignedToddlBU.DataBind();
            dialogAssignedToddlBU.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(String.Empty, String.Empty));
            dialogAssignedToddlBU.SelectedIndex = -1;

            dialogAssignedToddlRegion.ClearSelection();
            dialogAssignedToddlRegion.Enabled = false;
            dialogAssignedToddlCity.ClearSelection();
            dialogAssignedToddlCity.Enabled = false;
            dialogAssignedToddlCity.Items.Clear();
            dialogAssignedToddlCity.DataBind();
            dialogAssignedToddlCompanies.ClearSelection();
            dialogAssignedToddlCompanies.Enabled = false;
        }
```

Not much to see here, basically I am cascading a whole bunch of other drop downs.  Notice the `hdnOpenAssignedTo.Value = "1";` this is the field that keeps the dialog open based on the value 1.  And of course the dialog stays open however it flickers the grid and then opens...I want it to appear not to flicker or refresh to the end user.

Does this help or what other information do I need to post?

Thanks

Comment: Is hidden field that hold the state also inside UpdatePanel?

Comment: Can you please provide a more complete code example? At least the HMTL and JavaScript.

Comment: @JoshuaWilson - I have posted additional information.

Comment: @JonH Thanks for the update. How are the dropdowns being populated as you cascade them?  Or did I miss that?  Does the "filtering" use the server to update the options in the follow-on dropdowns?

Comment: @JoshuaWilson - See the code I posted (the code behind C# info).  The drop downs get loaded server side.  If this was all client side I wouldn't have this issue.  But again this all is working, the issue is not that something is not cascading.  The issue is the jquery dialog div refreshes, flickers due to the postback of a selectedindexchanged event from the drop down...I want to avoid that...and the entire page is in an update panel including the div dialog.

Comment: I am sorry, I am having a hard time wrapping my head around your code to be able to see the problem.  There just isn't enough here for me to reproduce the problem.  Please don't take offense, it is just how I process things. Are you able to share your code in [gist](https://gist.github.com/) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? If not, I understand.

Comment: ^^ I second this request, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Put all your script after your update panel like following

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
// your other controls
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<script type=""text/javascript">

$("#dialogAssignedTo").hide();
    $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        appendTo: "form:first",
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        modal: true
    });

$("#MainContent_hlAT").click(function (evt) {
                $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog("open");
                evt.preventDefault();
            });


if ($("#MainContent_hdnOpenAssignedTo").val() === "1") {
        $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog("open");
    } else {
        $("#dialogAssignedTo").hide();
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually solve your problem by removing all instances of the dialog except the last one (which would have the actual state of your drop downs)before initializing the dialog.And only append to the form after this trick.

```
    $('#dialogAssignedTo').not(':last').remove();

   $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto',
    modal: true
    });

$('#dialogAssignedTo').parent().appendTo($('form:first'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Check if:

- The hidden field has the correct value when checking its value on the client side before and after async postback:

  $("#MainContent_hdnOpenAssignedTo").val()
- The result of this expression is different when the hidden field has/does not have the (runat="server") attribute before and after async postback:

If this does not help, share more your UpdatePanel definition and underlying HTML before and after async postback.

Answer (score -1):

> it's similiar problem, i need to see your full code to check the
>   problem or maybe you can try to unbind the event click

```
$("#MainContent_hlAT").unbind("click").click(function (evt) {
    $("#dialogAssignedTo").dialog("open");
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```